# Reading new line as two characters

Tags: java, string, escaping, newline, string-length

I have written a small program

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\n";
        System.out.println(s.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The program gives the length as `1` and treats `\n` as single new line character.

My requirement is to treat `\n` as normal string so with `2` characters (First character `\` and second character `n`), what can be done to achieve it?

NOTE: 1) We can't change the string to add additional escape character. 
      2) We don't want to use any additional 3rd Party library

Comment: Why can't you change the string?

Comment: @ModDL: We can't change the string as it is given by some other persona...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) utility class from `commons-lang`.

```
String s = "\n";
s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s);
System.out.println(s.length());
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Output:

```
2
\
n
```

If you absolutely can't use a library like `commons-lang`, then you can write your own method to do it. You can browse through the code of the above class to see an example of how you can escape the string to account for different special characters.

Comment: I don't want to use any additional library. Can we do without additional libraries?

Comment: @Abhinav In this case you can write your own method... You can have a look at the way the above class does it. It basically parses each character in the string and escapes it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`We can't change the string to add additional escape character.`

I guess that is not possible because `\n` has a special meaning when used in String. 
Escape the backslash with double backslash like this `\\n`
This shall give you length as 2

```
String str = "\\n";
System.out.println(str.length());
```

Or try using apache commons-lang's

```
StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava()
```

Comment: The last sentence of OP's post is *NOTE: We can't change the string to add additional escape character.*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. The issue is that "\n" is one character. The single backslash is an escape.

```
char ch = '\n'; // <-- not two characters. it's one.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as that:

Once you go past the line

```
String s = "\n";
```

s will contain a single new line character, and there's nothing you can do about it.
You can obviously create a new String and replace all new line characters by "\n", but I don't think that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could search through the string and replace all character versions of /n with //n.

```
String s = convertNewLineChars("\n");

public String convertNewLineChars(String s)
{
    //for each character in string, replace '\n' with \\n
}
```

**Edit**

Use an enum for all your possible special characters

```
public enum SpecialCharacter
{
    NEWLINE('\n', "\\\\n"), //see note at the bottom of the answer for why 
    RETURN('\r', "\\\\r");  //there are four backslashes.

    private char character;
    private String charAsString;

    private SpecialCharacter(char character, String charAsString)
    {
        this.character = character;
        this.charAsString = charAsString;
    }

    public char getCharacter()
    {
        return this.character;
    }

    public String getCharAsString()
    {
        return this.charAsString;
    }

    public static SpecialCharacter[] getAllCharacters()
    {
        return new SpecialCharacter[] {NEWLINE, RETURN}; //etc...
    }
}
```

Create a static method for removing these characters

```
public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String s)
{
    String returnString = s;
    for (SpecialCharacter character : SpecialCharacter.getAllCharacters())
    {
        returnString = returnString.replaceAll("["+character.getCharacter()+"]", character.getCharAsString());
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Then you can say something like:

```
String s = removeSpecialCharacters("\nfdafhoean\noasd\r\rjfoi");
System.out.println(s);
```

This will work for any SpecialCharacter you add to the enum.

*Note that replaceAll() will consume the extra backslash... if you simply call `System.out.println(SpecialCharacter.NEWLINE.getCharAsString());` you will receive the output of `\\n`

Comment: New Line is just an example, the same holds good for others also like `\r`

Answer (score -1):

Just use another \ character infront of the \n to convert \n (new line) to \n two characters

Comment: The last sentence of OP's post is *NOTE: We can't change the string to add additional escape character.*